# Write Linux kernel in Python and compile with Cython

Tags: python, linux, kernel

Python compiles to C compatible bytecode with Cython. You rewrite Linux kernel source code files something.c in Python and compile with Cython. 
Is it possible to compile Python files to bytecode using Cython without Python's memory management and then insert them into the linking process during the normal kernel compilation?

Comment: CPython *does not compile to C*.

Comment: What do you mean by _compile CPython files to C_?? Cpython is already written in C language.

Comment: Thank you, /u/juanpa.arrivillaga, I updated the question.

Comment: ARK1375, that's a great physics question you've asked about the point of world view for a photon. Did you figure it out yet?

Comment: Any Python variables would require Python's object reference system which implies memory mgmt. If you only used C types it might not, but it still generates code that is all calls into the runtime system. Not sure how you could make that into a kernel module. Try it. You can see the generated C code.

Comment: Hmm, I found something close to Python that can potentially do this - Nim? https://github.com/dom96/nimkernel